# Codename One navigating forms

Tags: navigation, codenameone

I'm trying to navigate to a new form after authentication. After authentication, it returns to the previous form with show(). I know I can use showForm("", null) in an Action, but how can I move to a new form in showAuthentication()?

Is there anything show() can be replaced with to navigate to an all new Form?

```
public void showAuthentication()
{
    final ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            Dropbox.getInstance().setToken((String)e.getSource());
        }
    };

    final Form old = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();
    final String responseType = "token";
    final String clientID = "xxxxxxxxx";
    final String redirectURI = "https://google.com";

    String endpoint = "https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/authorize";
    endpoint += "?response_type=" + responseType;
    endpoint += "&client_id=" + clientID;
    endpoint += "&redirect_uri=" + redirectURI;

    Form current = new Form("Login");
    current.setScrollable(false);

    if(old != null)
    {
        Command cancel = new Command("Cancel") {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                old.showBack();
            }
        };
        current.addCommand(cancel);
        current.setBackCommand(cancel);
    }

    WebBrowser web = new WebBrowser() {
        @Override
        public void onLoad(String url)
        {
            System.out.println(url);

            if(url.startsWith(redirectURI))
            {
                if(url.indexOf("#") > -1)
                {
                    String accessToken = url.substring(url.indexOf("#") + 1);
                    token = accessToken.substring(accessToken.indexOf("=") + 1, accessToken.indexOf("&"));

                    al.actionPerformed(new ActionEvent(token));
                    old.show();
                }
            }
        }
    };

    web.setURL(endpoint);

    current.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    current.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, web);

    current.show();
}
```

}

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by "authentication", how do you authenticate and what are you trying to do?

Comment: Using dropbox, I click on a button to authenticate with Dropbox, and at the end of the authentication process, the app returns to the original page using show(). What if I want the app to open a different GUI element?

Answer (score 0):

Override this:

```
protected void beforeNewForm(Form f) {
    f.setBackCommand(null);
}
```

Add above codes and it will not return to Authenticaton page when back button is pressed.
Hope it answer your answer

Comment: No, that's not what I'm asking. There's no cancel button. My app authenticates through dropbox. I have it returning to the previous page, but I don't have to. I would rather it return to a different page. Any way that you know of to make that happen?

Comment: Sure, check the edits. It's the standard Dropbox authentication method.

Answer (score 0):

You are invoking `old.show()` in your code. Instead just invoke `newForm.show()` or `showForm` to the desired destination and that should work.